# What is your best friend Jake trying to tell you in his email?

Tags: cipher, story, steganography, computer-puzzle

You and your best friend Jake always walk two miles to school together every day. On one particular day, when you leave for school, you realize that your friend isn't there. Thinking that he's probably sick or something, you carry on as if nothing happened.

When you return home a few hours later and open your computer, you find an email in your inbox. The email is as follows:

> **From**: Jake Green <i.am.jake@gmail.com>
>   **Sent**: Fri, March 23, 2018 3:11 PM EDT
>   **To**: Arnav Borborah <arnavb@gmail.com>
>   **Subject**: I wasn't at school today, what did we do in class?
>
> Hey Arnav,
>
> **Important:** I didn't go to school today, obviously as I wasn't in class. So I probably missed a f*e*w assignments. Could you send their details to me via email?
>
> Most likely, you're probably wondering what happened to me. Well, it turn*s* out I'm down with the flu. (I know, it sucks -_-) I was fine a few days ago and I suddenly just caught the bug that's been going around.
>
> Given the circumstances, the most appropriate thing for me to do is to get my rest. I'll probably be back in sch*o*ol in a few days at most. I'm fine with missing school, but the thing is, I have nothing to do lying in bed aaaaallll day long... ;-)
>
> Unfortunately, this means *t*hat  I'm going to have to keep pestering you through email to submit some of my assignments in class (I'll send the work to you). I hope you don't mind!
>
> Right now, I'm going to go back to sle*e*p, since it is probably a good idea to be resting while I'm down with the flu. Don't forget to send me today's assignment details!
>
> ...Oh yeah, before I forget: Since I'm sick, I wasn't able to turn in my assignment to M*r*s. Johnson. I've added *i*t as an attachment, so could you please print it out and turn it in? :*c*
>
> Thanks,
>   - Your buddy, Jake

After reading the email, you open the attachment, which is as follows:

```
v#>"F",>v"dSs">v>v>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
>>^"gX",>>>>>>^v",#########<888888##11#####v
##"a">>v^v<<>#v<K,>>>>>><><<<##333####<9#0#v
##v>>>>v,,"oK"<#"v6#>#<#4<>v######<abc#[]##v
"2`~x",>"Y",>>>>^@<#######ZZ#####>####w#c##v
~!~!&!!!!v^v^v^v^###@@@###E<E####^~~~~~##s#v
WEWFFFFFFF<>44@@@@@######W##<<##;'##aaaa###v
<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<^v^v<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
```

From the looks of the attachment, it seems that it got garbled somehow, so you decide to reply back to your friend to tell him. As you are doing so, something suddenly catches your eye. After carefully inspecting the contents of the email, you run to your phone and call the police to report an incident.

> **What message do you find in the email Jake sent to you and what incident do you report to the police?**
>   (Your solution should contain the steps you followed to solve the problem)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If we look at the italicised letters, we see that

> they spell "esoteric". This is a hint that the given block of text is an esoteric programming language - specifically, it's [Befunge](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Befunge).

Interpreting the block of text this way gives

> `FoKYK`, which is an image on stack.imgur.com (as hinted by the first letters of each paragraph).
>
>  [image]
>  This image is pigpen cipher for **HELP FAMILY KIDNAPPED WEST MAIN ST**, so the incident is a **kidnapping on West Main Street**.